# How to print a response from Express.js into the POST requesting html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express

I wanted to print the login validation messages on the login page itself. But the response is being printed on a new blank page. Is there any way to fetch the response and print in on any existing div tags?

I'm using Express.js to handle the login validation.

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var user_name=req.body.user;
    var password=req.body.pwd;

    console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);

    if (user_name=="sudheesh" && password=="pass") {
        sess = req.session;
        sess.user=user_name;
        console.log("Logged in..");
        res.send('done');
    }
    else {
        res.send('not_done');
    }
});
```

The HTML script looks like this,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var user,pwd;
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            email=$("#user").val();
            pass=$("#pwd").val();
            /*
            * Perform some validation here.
            */
            $.post("http://localhost:3000/login",{user:user,pwd:pwd},function(data){ 
              console.log(data);
        if(data=='done')           
        {
            alert("you have logged in..!");
            window.location.href="/about";
        }
    });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The above code will only print done or not_done on a new page. I wanted to fetch that value and print something on the login page itself.

Comment: Your script prints nothing. It just alerts "you have logged in..!" if login was successful and then redirects to your about page. So I don't understand your problem.

Comment: The log in is working fine. But I'm not getting the alert and is not redirecting to the about page.

Comment: Is the `#submit` element a link by any chance? This could be cancelling the request (even it it appears to be successful server-side). Adding an `e.preventDefault()` inside the click function would solve this.

Comment: Also... I'd take a look at using passport.js or similar - simplifies a lot of the authentication!